# Cakephp 3.x Saving multiple tables

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0, cakephp

In my cakephp (3.3) project, How to save multiple tables in a single save. My association is as follows, also I am giving my code here.

Table1 : users

### In class UsersTable extends Table

```
$this->hasOne('ProfileDetails', [
'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

Table2 : profile_details

### In class ProfileDetailsTable extends Table

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

What should be the data format to save multiple tables? 
In my template I have added the following , for now I have used only few fields

```
$this->Form->input('User.username',['type' => 'text','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
$this->Form->input('User.password',['type' => 'password','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
$this->Form->input('User.email',['type' => 'text','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
$this->Form->input('ProfileDetail.first_name',['type' => 'text','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
```

In the controller before saving i have debuged which gives result as follows

```
debug($this->request->data);
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
debug($user); 
exit;
$this->Users->save($user)
```

### Result of debug

```
\src\Controller\UsersController.php (line 39)
[
'User' => [
'username' => 'Tester',
'password' => '43434324',
'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
'role' => 'admin'
],
'ProfileDetail' => [
'first_name' => 'Tester'
]
]
\src\Controller\UsersController.php (line 41)
object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

'User' => [
'username' => 'Tester',
'password' => '43434324',
'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
'role' => 'admin'
],
'ProfileDetail' => [
'first_name' => 'Tester'
],
'[new]' => true,
'[accessible]' => [
'*' => true
],
'[dirty]' => [
'User' => true,
'ProfileDetail' => true
],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [
'email' => [
'_required' => 'This field is required'
]
],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Users'

}
```

Could you please suggest me how to save this data in multiple tables with single save with validation?

Comment: put **ProfileDetails** instead **ProfileDetail** 

`$this->Form->input('ProfileDetails.first_name' ...`

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski Singular is the correct default, but it is also is ment to be underscored, ie `profile_detail`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your debug, there is an error saying the email field is required. Maybe that is your problem..

Answer (score 0):

If still not working , try this:

```
replace User by users
and ProjectDetail by project_details
```

In your form. And also remove joinType from following:

```
$this->hasOne('ProfileDetails', [
'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

Comment: Instead of User.username , User.password and User.email try using just username,password and email...and keep project_details.first_name for ProjectDetail.first_name..

Comment: @ManoharKhadka `hasOne` associations by default use singular names, ie `profile_detail`. Also the join type has nothing to do with saving, but only with retrieving data.

Comment: Still no luck with the following data


\src\Controller\UsersController.php (line 51)

[
 'username' => 'testuser',
 'password' => '123456',
 'email' => 'testuser@gmail.com',
 'role' => 'author',
 'profile_details' => [
  'first_name' => 'test',
  'last_name' => 'fname',
  'phone' => '444444'
 ]
]